# Debugging python SWIG object

Tags: python, c++, swig

I'm in a situation where I'm writing some new python code to replace some code written for a legacy system. The legacy system is referencing some C++ code through a SWIG wrapper. There's one particular point in the legacy python code that uses a method from the SWIG wrapper with an output I don't understand how to interpret.

<hub_logging.StringList; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'std::vector< std::string > *' at 0xed1e0a88> >

Here's the relevant portion of the code from the python perspective:

```
#import swig wrapper hgrm_messages
import hgrm_messages

#declare an object with the JobInstanceDefinition class through SWIG  
definition = hgrm_messages.JobInstanceDefinition()

#loop through arguments list and place into a vector using the push_back method through SWIG
for argument in agruments:
    definition.arguments.push_back(str(argument))
```

When I debug this code the value of definition.arguments is shown as (same as above):

<hub_logging.StringList; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'std::vector< std::string > *' at 0xed1e0a88> >

I'm looking for some help understanding the value of this output. I've familiarized myself with SWIG and have some working knowledge of C++ (my python knowledge is far greater). I'm not sure how to traceback this output to the C++ funtion producing it.

Any help or thoughts appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The display below is SWIG's default representation of the proxy wrapper object for the vector template it has wrapped:

```
<hub_logging.StringList; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'std::vector< std::string > *' at 0xed1e0a88> >
```

Here's a minimal example .i file and use case:

```cpp
%module test

%include <std_vector.i>  // SWIG typemaps for std::vector<>
%include <std_string.i>  // SWIG typemaps for std::string

// Gives an alias and instructs SWIG to generate wrappers
// for this specific template instantiation.
%template(StringList) std::vector<std::string>;

// Generate both code and a wrapper for the following class.
%inline %{
class Definition {
public:
    std::vector<std::string> arguments;
};
%}
```

Demo:

```py
>>> import test
>>> definition = test.Definition()
>>> definition.arguments
<test.StringList; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'std::vector< std::string > *' at 0x00000289E88CA120> >
>>> definition.arguments.push_back("arg1")
>>> definition.arguments.push_back("arg2")
>>> list(definition.arguments)  # wrapper is iterable, convert to Python list
['arg1', 'arg2']
```

If you don't like the default display representation, you can override it in SWIG similar to overriding `__repr__()` for Python by adding an extension to the vector template:

```cpp
%extend std::vector<std::string> {
    std::string __repr__() {
        std::string tmp {"StringList(["};
        for(size_t i = 0; i < $self->size() - 1; ++i)
            tmp += "\"" + $self->at(i) + "\", ";
        if($self->size() > 0)
            tmp += "\"" + $self->at(self->size() - 1) + "\"";
        tmp += "])";
        return tmp;
    }
};
```

Now the demo output is:

```py
>>> import test
>>> definition = test.Definition()
>>> definition.arguments.push_back('arg1')
>>> definition.arguments
StringList(["arg1"])
>>> definition.arguments.push_back('arg2')
>>> definition.arguments
StringList(["arg1", "arg2"])
```

Note my extension doesn't properly escape embedded quotes in the string, but you should get the idea.

Comment: Getting back to this.

Thanks! The little piece of information I need was that the wrapper creates a python iterable which needs to be passed to a python function like list to make it readable. 

Now I need to better understand the encoding. I've noticed a prefacing u (to indicate unicode) is present in arguments string. But when passed to the .push_back method through the SWIG wrapper and viewed as a list. The prefacing u is gone.

Comment: @ChaseSchuette It's not really an iterable.  It is actually an array but the default display representation doesn't show the elements.  `list()` extracts the elements, but you coudl also do `for item in definition.arguments: print(item)`, or just `print(definition.arguments[0])` for example.  Or as I provided you can override the display representation.  The SWIG typemaps for `std::string` accept a Unicode string but encode it to UTF-8 when passed to C++.  In Python 3 `u"string"` and `"string"` are both Unicode strings, the preceding `u` is for backward compatibility with Python 2-ported code.